# Drools: case insensitive compare?

Tags: java, drools

I need to compare two fields in a case insensitive way. I have a rule something like this:

```
foo : ObjectTypeA()
bar : ObjectTypeB( name == foo.name )
```

And that works for strings that are the same case. What I need is something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
foo : ObjectTypeA()
bar : ObjectTypeB( name.equalsIgnoreCase( foo.name ) )
```

Any suggestions on how to get that to work? Googling hits on suggestions to use "matches", but the matches operator only seems to work against a hard coded pattern.

Comment: The equalsIgnoreCase() method should work. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates it not work so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i have answered similar query here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027483/13380643

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use eval. equalsIgnoreCase method also had a typo in your example code.

```
bar : ObjectTypeB(  eval( name.equalsIgnoreCase( foo.name ) ) )
```

If you want to use something like:

```
ObjectType( name equalsIgnoreCase foo.name )
```

You can take a look at Drools custom operators. Example:
http://members.inode.at/w.laun/drools/CustomOperatorHowTo.html

Comment: In Drools 5.3 and newer, you can imply the eval simply by wrapping the evaluation in parenthesis, (just drop the word eval).  Also, I haven't tested this specifically with the equalsIgnoreCase() but according to the Drools documentation, you are supposed to be able to code the eval() expressions without the eval keyword, and without the parenthesis when used inside an object expression.
Something like:  ObjectTypeB ( name.equalsIgnoreCase(foo.name) )

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a custom operator as Toni mentioned you can copy & paste and adjust this class to support the `equalsIgnoreCase` method:

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/base/evaluators/StrEvaluatorDefinition.java

Edson

Comment: I picked Toni's answer since it works, but I wanted to make sure this one got +1 as well since I think it actually helps me solve a different Drools question :)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/7.73.0.Final/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/base/evaluators/StrEvaluatorDefinition.java

Answer (score -5):

== : mean to compare the object reference while

name.equalsIgnoresCase( foo.name ) : mean to compare the contents.

let suppose
   soo.name = "ram";    foo.name = "ram";
if(soo.name ==  foo.name) return **false**
because of the only content is same not the object.

if we say like foo.name = "ram";
  **soo.name = foo.name;

if(soo.name == foo.name) ** return **true**

Comment: In Drools LHS the == does the same as equals, compares the content.