# EqualsIgnoreCase on Drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine, mvel

I am trying to rewrite my drl from using regex to equalsIgnoreCase as I think its faster. I am not sure its faster though. However, drools doesn't like it for some reason and I get unknown error.

The one on top works, but the one using equalsIgnoreCase doesn't

```
rule "name"
salience 0
activation-group "flow"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop true
when
    $vurderinger: Vurderinger(vurdering1909 != null &&
                              vurdering1909.verdi matches "(?i)^FOO$")
then
    modify( $vurderinger ) { setVurdering1913(new DroolsType("SHOW")) }
end


rule "name"
salience 0
activation-group "flow"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop true
when
    $vurderinger: Vurderinger(vurdering1909 != null &&
                 eval("FOO".equalsIgnoreCase(vurdering1909.verdi)))
then
    modify( $vurderinger ) { setVurdering1913(new DroolsType("SHOW")) }
end
```

Can anyone spot the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within eval, stick to Java: refer to bound variables, use getter.

```
when
$vurderinger: Vurderinger($v: vurdering1909 != null &&
             eval("FOO".equalsIgnoreCase($v.getVerdi())))
then
```

**Edit** Not knowing the class definition, the error and the version, I advise using eval/Java, to be on the safe side, no matter what the Drools version is. For 6.3.0, you can omit eval, and it works.

```
when
$vurderinger: Vurderinger(vurdering1909 != null &&
              "FOO".equalsIgnoreCase(vurdering1909.verdi))
then
```

Comment: Hmm why is that? I am using mvel. Is there any other way of doing it without using eval?

Answer (score 0):

I have given solution for decision table i.e:

[image]

`javaObject.getRisk().equalsIgnoreCase("$param")`

for drools rules

````
rule "Rule To Check String Contains"
when
Pojo(name.contains("Loans"))
then
System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
end

rule "Rule To Check String Equals"
when
Pojo(name.equals("Personal Loans, Insuarnce"))
then
System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
end

rule "Rule To Check String EqualsIgnoreCase"
when
Pojo(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Personal loans, insuarnce"))
then
System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
end```
````